# How to set a Mnemonic for a JTree/JList/JTable

Tags: java, swing, testing, key-bindings

They don't have setMnemonic(), as Buttons do.

I'm trying to build some automated UI testing. Making the entire UI keyboard driven is vital for this. Using mnemonics (accelerators or shortcuts) to move between widgets is a tried and true method.

I can't seem to figure out how to set a mnemonic for the above components though.
There are ways to brute-force the keyboard navigation, tabbing between elements or manually register global accelerators. But if I have to go that far I'd at least like some opinions on the best practice for this.

<edit>

camickr was right. I just had to relax and finish reading the docs on the subject. then it became quite simple. Here's is the final result for anyone doing a search.

```
treeWidget                                     
  .getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)
  .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(LIST_MN,InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK), "focus_jtree");

treeWidget   
  .getActionMap()                        
  .put("focus_jtree", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override                    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
      treeWidget.requestFocusInWindow();
  }});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the Swing tutorial in [How to Use Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

> But I can't seem to figure out how to set focus to one of these components using only keyboard events.

Not sure what you mean by that. You can tab to any of those components.

Comment: That might work, but its a rather poor solution. I'll have to keep track of how many tabs it takes to go from one widget to the one I want. Which could be different per test. As each test would end on a different widget. Also every UI changed would also change the numbers. I'll edit my question a bit.

Comment: @DragonFax, I in fact did suggest you use Key Binding which is how accelerators/mnemonics work. Have you read the tutorial yet? My second comment was made because your original question did not have enough context and I wasn't exactly sure what you were asking.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I was responding to the "tab" suggestion only. I glomped onto that part of your answer and didn't let go.

Answer (score 1):

My current solution is

```
JLabel jLabel = new JLabel("List");
  jLabel.setDisplayedMnemonic(LIST_MN);
  jLabel.setLabelFor(treeWidget);
  add(jLabel);
  add(treeWidget);
```

Seems to do the job, but my widgets don't always have labels. So I'm just adding labels to give them easy mnemonics. And the labels often don't contain the mnemonic character anyways.